# Random faces appeared on object

Tags: edit-mode, faces

I'll start with pictures:

[image]

These are not vertices... they are faces, but I don't know how they got "duplicated" or what. As you can see down, in the 3D Viewport's footer, I'm in face selection mode.

[image]

How do i fix this without deleting that edge or face? Because if I delete it, I'll have to redo it all again...

Comment: It's one of the easiest slips to make: Right-clicking doesn't cancel an extrusion, it only cancels the transform you make immediately afterwards, and because nothing's moved, it's invisible. So remember to Ctrl-Z if you want to cancel an extrusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably started an Extrusion (<kbd>E</kbd>) and then "accepted" it without moving the vertices, effectively creating a zero-width rim.

Problems like this are easily fixed by selecting all your vertices and doing <kbd>W</kbd> > "*Remove Doubles*" ("remove double vertices" since Blender 2.8)

Comment: Yep, it worked. Thank you very much. Il accept answer soon! :)